# keyboard shortcut works in one layout, not in another

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, keyboard-layout, gnome-terminator, keyboard-event

I use `terminator` on `arch linux` / `Gnome 3` and in there I switch between the tabs with `Control L + Page Up / Down`. When I'm in the `de` or `en` keyboard layout, this works fine. However, I figured out that when I'm using the `no` keyboard layout, this exact same key combination doesn't make `terminator` to switch between the tabs, instead it prints `5~` on the terminal.

I already checked the `Show Keyboard Layout` window to check, that the `Control L`, `Page Up` and `Page Down` keys aren't remapped or something and they are exactly the same between the `de` and the `no` layout.

Where does this behavior come from?

Edit: I dug a bit deeper and found, that the only difference, `xev` shows for both combinations is the `state` variable, which is `0x4004` in `de` and `0x4` in `no`. What is the `0x4000` flag for? Why is it set in the `de` layout and not in the `no` one?

Comment: The reason is that when you switch layouts, under the hood, that's encoded as using a “layout-switch” modifier. Some applications see a key with the layout-switch modifier and treat it as distinct from the bare key. Other applications ignore the unknown modifier. If you load a different configuration instead of having a dual-layout configuration you won't have this problem.